# How to properly use "while not" loops in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, logic

I am learning python since a couple of days now. I did understand the concept of while and for loops in general. However, at the moment I am trying to understand the code written for a hangman game, and I stumbled over the following lines of code:

```
import random
from words import word_list


def get_word():
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    return word.upper()


def play(word):
    word_completion = "_" * len(word)
    guessed = False
    guessed_letters = []
    guessed_words = []
    tries = 6
    print("Let's play Hangman!")
    print(display_hangman(tries))
    print(word_completion)
    print("\n")
    while not guessed and tries > 0:
```

There was a variable called "guessed" initially set to False.

at the beginning of the while loop, it's written:

```
while not guessed ...
```

But isn't this like a double negation? When *guessed = False*, then shouldn't *not guessed == True?* so that we could also just write *while True* and wouldn't even need the variable *guessed*?

Or how can I understand the while not concept in general?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I think its more from a code readability perspective. Like in the game initially you haven’t taken a guess so guessed is false and you will stay in the lwhile loop until the player has not guessed the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best explanation for `while not guessed` is that it is essentially saying "while guessed is not equal to true". This is to say it is basically "while guessed is false." So the while loop will run for as long as guessed is false and tries > 0. However, if guess is every made to be true, then the while loop will stop running.

The key thing is that not doesn't meaning negation in this sense. It is just meaning that the while loop runs as long as the value of guessed is false and NOT true. I understand the confusion in this but it is an important fact to know.

Answer (score 0):

> But isn't this like a double negation? When `guessed = False`, then shouldn't `not guessed == True`?

Yes.

> so that we could also just write `while True` and wouldn't even need the variable `guessed`?

No, because the value of the variable `guessed` can (and most likely will) change to `True` at some point during the loop execution -- after all, a variable is called a variable because its value can vary between different states of program execution. Then `not guessed` will evaluate to `False`, and the `while` loop will terminate.
On the other hand, a `while True` loop would run infinitely because `True` will always remain `True`.

That's the whole point of `while` constructs: One uses a variable (or some more complex condition involving varying values, such as `not variable`) which initially evaluates to `True` and makes the loop run, but when some condition is met will change its value to `False`, causing the loop to terminate.

Comment: but you approved that when guessed = False --> not guessed = True

Comment: within the for loop I am referring to (https://github.com/kiteco/python-youtube-code/blob/master/build-hangman-in-python/hangman.py), there is another guessed = True which ends the code. But I don't understand the logic behind this. I mean, it's like while the loop is true ..... guessed = true. It seems to be redundant... Sorry, I am still a newbie...

Comment: A loop can not be true or false. The condition `not guessed` can be true or false. And that condition is reevaluated after every loop iteration. After that iteration in which `guessed` becomes `True`, the whlile condition does *not* any longer evaluate to `True`. So `not guessed` can not simply be replaced by `True`.

Comment: First: Thanks a lot for your comments and patience. Unfortunately, I still don't get it. Isn't it like defining something: if I define a = b, then I could use a and b interchangeably. If I define "guessed = False", can't I use them interchangeably as well? When I negate guessed, it follows: "not guessed = True" (as discussed). Inside the while loop then, I would expect something like guessed = False, so that the condition of the while loop ("not guessed") is not fulfilled, since not guessed = True != guessed = False...

Comment: Yes, you can use the two sides of the assignment interchangeably -- as long as that assignment is active. But variables can be *reassigned*, thereby completely overriding the previous assignment. After setting `guessed = True`, `guessed` is no longer equal to `False`.

Comment: The condition `not guessed` is fulfilled after the initial assignment `guessed = False`, before the first round of the loop. At that point, the loop runs. The condition is no longer fulfilled after the round in which the reassignment `guessed = True` happens. At that point, the loop stops.

Comment: that's it. Understood. Thanks a lot!